How to use regular-expressions in C language
I'm a new bike in C language, after some simple examples and best practices of how to use regular expressions in ANSI C.
I have simple test, want to get date in an description string bellow
"{d(02/01/2019)}-call Ms.ha check this case". I mean want to get "02/01/2019"
this is my code
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr) (sizeof((arr)) / sizeof((arr)[0]))
// initialize target string and regular expression string

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     regex_t preg;

        char *string = "{d(02/01/2019)}-call Ms.ha check this case";
        char *pattern="?[0-9]+(\\/[0-9]+)+(\\/[0-9]+)?"; // I'm stupid pattern in here.
        size_t nmatch = 2;
        regmatch_t pmatch[2];


        regcomp(&preg, pattern, REG_EXTENDED);
        regexec(&preg, string, nmatch, pmatch, 0);

        printf("a matched substring \"%.*s\" is found at position %d to %d.\n",
         pmatch[1].rm_eo - pmatch[1].rm_so, &string[pmatch[1].rm_so],
         pmatch[1].rm_so, pmatch[1].rm_eo - 1);

        regfree(&preg);


        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


How to create pattern in this case,
Thanks Advice.

"[0-9]+(/[0-9]+)+(/[0-9]+)"

You do not need any separators at the start and the end (possibly influenced by a history of PHP? I don't know any other language that requires them inside a string). You also do not need to escape slashes, as they have no special meaning here (it is only needed in languages/constructs where slash is the delimiter).
Also, you want pmatch[0], not pmatch[1]. The latter just gives you the contents of the first capture group, /01.
You will want to check the result of regcomp and regexec; ignoring them is inviting bugs into your life. In your case, ? at the start of your pattern was generating REG_BADRPT (invalid operand of a repetition operator) in regcomp. For example:
int err;
err = regcomp(&preg, pattern, REG_EXTENDED);
if (err) {
    size_t errbuf_size = regerror(err, &preg, NULL, 0);
    char* errbuf = (char*) malloc(errbuf_size);
    if (!errbuf) {
        perror("error allocating memory");
        exit(255);
    };
    regerror(err, &preg, errbuf, errbuf_size);
    fprintf(stderr, "Regex error: %s\n", errbuf);
    exit(1);
};

regexec should give a smaller range of problems; if 0, you're good; if REG_NOMATCH, self-explanatory. If anything other than that... you can do the same thing as above, if you want to know what happened.
